# How to link to the "main page" with Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

In doxygen comments, `@ref` or `@link` can be used to link to various things such as pages, sections, or files.

But how do I link to the main page?  This page is identified by the `@mainpage` command, but in contrast to the `@page` command, `@mainpage` does not include any name for the page that could be used with `@ref` or `@link`.

Follow-up question: My project is structured in multiple parts that each generate a tag file.  How do I link to the main page of one part from within another part?  I've been looking inside the tag file but I can't seem to find any item that would refer to the main page.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? regarding the `@mainpage` have a look at the `@anchor` command. Please add a small example to your question as well as the settings in your doxygen configuration files that are different from the default doxygen configuration file.

Comment: I'm using version 1.8.16